# Is there third party API for perfect BiDi language support (i.e Arabic)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display arabic text on TextView, but the vovel characters (e.g Shadda "0x90", sukun "0x92" etc) not getting positioned well on other characters. I have come to know that BiDi work in android is incomplete and there are third party API that handles this problem nicely..

Is there any free API available for me??? Please help

Please see following screenshot, i have tried so many fonts but the problem is same.
[image]